# Can't find database on DB browser SQLite?

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite, android-sqlite

I am a beginner and creating a registration database for a school project, when I go to DB Browser for SQLite and open my file there are no tables or contents? Would it have something to do with my use of onCreate or onUpgrade? I've done a lot of research but the results I get are always from a really long time ago, and also I really do not understand them. When I enter information on my emulator I also get the error code 'SQLiteException: no such table'. I am really unsure of what to do with my code.

```
package android.example.rise;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.nfc.Tag;
import android.text.Html;
import android.util.Log;

public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    public static final String DATABASE_NAME="register.db";
    public static final String TABLE_NAME="register.db";
    public static final String COL_1="ID";
    public static final String COL_2="first";
    public static final String COL_3="second";
    public static final String COL_4="last";
    public static final String COL_5="email";
    public static final String COL_6="password";

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {
        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("CREATE TABLE registeruser (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, first TEXT, second TEXT, last TEXT, email TEXT, password TEXT)");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
        onCreate(sqLiteDatabase);

    }

    public long addUser(String first, String middle, String last, String user, String password) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put("first", first);
        contentValues.put("second", middle);
        contentValues.put("last", last);
        contentValues.put("email", user);
        contentValues.put("password", password);
        long res = db.insert("registeruser", null, contentValues);
        return res;

    }

    public boolean checkUser(String email, String password){
        String[] column = {COL_1};
        SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
        String selection = COL_5 + "=?" + " and " + COL_6 + "=?";
        String[] selectionArgs = { email, password } ;
        Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_NAME,column,selection,selectionArgs,null,null,null);
        int count = cursor.getCount();
        cursor.close();
        db.close();

        if(count>0)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this line:

```
public static final String TABLE_NAME="register.db";
```

I guess by mistake, you define the table's name the same as the database's name,
although in the `CREATE` statement:

```
sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("CREATE TABLE registeruser (.....)");
```

you create the table with name `registeruser`. 
Later in your code you always use the variable `TABLE_NAME` which is different than the created table. 
Also, since you have defined variables for the names of the table and the columns, don't hardcode them again.
Change the declaration to:

```
public static final String TABLE_NAME="registeruser";
```

and the `CREATE` statement to:

```
sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(
    "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " (" + 
        COL_1 + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
        COL_2 + " TEXT, " + 
        COL_3 + " TEXT, " +
        COL_4 + " TEXT, " +
        COL_5 + " TEXT, " +
        COL_6 + " TEXT)"
);
```

then uninstall the app from the device to delete the database and rerun so the database is recreated with the proper name for the table.